# What do I add to this timer to display it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry for asking such a beginner question, but what do I add to display it on html?

```
DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    int tik = 60;
    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Countdown.Text = tik + " Seconds Remaining";
        if (tik > 0)
            tik--;
        else
            Countdown.Text = "Times Up";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `div` or other container to store the String in your html. For example, in your html you might add:

```
<div id="time-text"></div>
```

And then in your js, probably within the Tick method, you might add:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#time-text').html(Countdown.Text);
```

or

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('#time-text').innerHTML = Countdown.Text;
```

Comment: You need to put the js line *inside* the Tick method, at the end preferably. Just slapping the js line onto the beginning of your js code wont work. It doesn't know what the `Countdown` variable is at that point.

Comment: Sorry, could you update the jsfiddle code for me to specifically see where to put it? because i placed it within the tick method, and it doesn't seem to diplay.

Comment: There might be a problem with my comp, but the timer doesn't pop out

Comment: This code doesn't create a *popout* timer per say. It sets the html of a container to the timer string every time the timer "Ticks"

Comment: should there be an output, as i only see a blank page?

Comment: something else must be broken then, this is very basic javascript code. :( sorry but I've never used mootools before.